# divide list of numbers into 5 groups in matlab

Tags: matlab-guide

I have a list of numbers,[1:20],that I need to divide five groups. This division can be randomly or other kind of classification. Any ideas of how to do this in matlab?

Comment: You might get some help if you show that you've attempted a solution.

Comment: For the random case you can do `randperm(20)` to get a vector of indices, then you can `reshape` the result or cut it into 5 separate vectors.